# Error: Array index out of range Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview

```
var longPressTarget: (cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath)?

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
   longPressTarget = (cell: self.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath), indexPath: indexPath)
}

func longPressHandler(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            if let _longPressTarget = longPressTarget {   
                let entity = coin[_longPressTarget.indexPath.item]
                let contextMenuController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
                let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: entity.pendingDelete ? "Undelete" : "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: togglePendingDelete)
            }
        }
}
```

Error is at: `let entity = coin[_longPressTarget.indexPath.item]`

coin:

```
var coin: [Receipts] = [Receipts] ()
```

-coin is called before `viewDidLoad`

Receipts: An entity in core data

I do not understand why the coin array is out of range?

I am trying to delete a `UICollectionViewCell` out of core data using a long press gesture recognizer

Comment: If you are using a `UICollectionView` why you don't get the `indexPath` for the selected cell instead of `longPressTarget.indexPath.item`, as the error said it give you and index outside the bound of the array

Comment: What's is `longPressTarget ` ?

Comment: var longPressTarget: (cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath)? //different line                                     
 
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        longPressTarget = (cell: self.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath), indexPath: indexPath)
    }     @VictorSigler

Comment: Please can you put the code in the question?

Comment: See my answer about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's fix your code by part, first you don't access to the cell at some `indexPath` calling the method `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. You can use the method `cellForItemAtIndexPath(_:)` like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     longPressTarget = (cell: self.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath), indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Nevertheless in you case I don't know for what you need the cell but...

In your other method you need to use the `indexPath.row` not the `indexPath.item`, there are different. So your code should like this:

```
func longPressHandler(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        if let _longPressTarget = longPressTarget {
            let indexPath = _longPressTarget.indexPath
            let entity = coin[indexPath.row]
            let contextMenuController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: entity.pendingDelete ? "Undelete" : "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: togglePendingDelete)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.